# How can i get the user object together with an extended profile model in DRF when i login and return the token object back in simple JWT

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have a custome user model with an extended one-to-one relationship with profile model, now i am using simple jwt for authentication so when i am returning the token object it should include the user and profile objects all together.
Here is my serializers

```py
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={"input_type": "password"}, write_only=True)
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['id', 'uuid','email', 'firstname', 'lastname','phone_number', 'user_level', 'password', 'password2', 'profile']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
            'uuid': {'read_only': True},
        }

    def save(self):
        user = MyUser(
            email=self.validated_data['email'], 
            firstname=self.validated_data['firstname'],
            lastname=self.validated_data['lastname'],
            user_level=self.validated_data['user_level'],
            phone_number=self.validated_data['phone_number'],
            )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match.'})
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

#logging user to get jwt token
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        # Add custom claims
        token['uuid'] = user.uuid
        token['email'] = user.email
        token['firstname'] = user.firstname
        token['lastname'] = user.lastname
        token['user_level'] = user.user_level
        token['phone_number'] = user.phone_number
        # token['profile'] = user.profile
        
        return token
```

I got the user object when returning the token object but i cannot include the profile object as i have commented out in the token serializer, i want both objects to come back as token object